# express, authentication without 401

Tags: node.js, authentication, express

This is a resume about an authentication method.
I tried to use `express.basicAuth`, but it forces the browser to ask for user and pass, and I need to use my own login page, like google, facebook yahoo...

Is this right? Is there any better way to do this?
I want to avoid modules, like passport, if I can.

I want to use a function like this, using auth middleware `(app.get('/loggedin', auth, function(req, res)...)`
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
app.use(express.session({
  store: new RedisStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379,
    db: 2,
    pass: 'RedisPASS'
  }), secret: '1234567890QWERTY'
}));

var auth = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.authStatus === 'loggedIn')
        next();
    else
        res.redirect('/login');
};

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("/");
    res.send('not authenticate');
});

app.get('/signin', function(req, res) {
    console.log("/signin");
    if (req.body.user && req.body.pass)
    {
       req.user = req.body.user;
       req.remoteUser = req.body.user;
       req.session.authStatus = 'loggedIn';

       req.session.lastPage = '/signin';
       res.redirect('/loggedin');
    }
    else
       res.redirect('/login');
});

app.get('/loggedin', auth, function(req, res) {
    if(req.session.lastPage) {
        res.write('Last page was: ' + req.session.lastPage + '. ');
    }

    req.session.lastPage = '/loggedin';
    res.write('Yeeeeeeeeeee');
    res.end();
});


app.get('/loggedin2', auth, function(req, res) {
    console.log("/loggedin2");
    if(req.session.lastPage) {
        res.write('Last page was: ' + req.session.lastPage + '. ');
    }

    req.session.lastPage = '/loggedin2';
    res.write('WoWWWWW!!!!!!');
    res.end();
});

app.get('/logout', auth, function(req, res) {
    console.log("/logout");
    req.session.destroy();
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log("/notlogged");
    res.send('enter user and pass...');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Comment: in my opinion, that's fine. very closer to what I've implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `passport` middleware module in npm — the `passport-local` module provides authentication against a local resource such as a database.

Comment: I tried to use this module, but if the user tries to access a page without a success login, the passport sends 401 to browser and the browser shows his default box for user and password, I tried to change it, but I couldn't. Then I have made this implementation without passport.